# TCP/IP between client and server having different IP types

Tags: sockets, http, tcp

I am new to TCP/IP programming. Currently I am developing a http client , I have a doubt what should I do when the IP address of client and server is of different types while creating sockets.

Like Client has IP which is of IPV4 and server has IP which is of IPV6 or vice versa. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Have you tried it already? Or being worried? You are taking care of something which is not cared by programming. No need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to connect an IPv6 client to an IPv4 server.

It is possible to connect an IPv4 client to an IPv6 server, but only if the server is running in a [dual stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Dual_IP_stack_implementation) mode, which uses [mapped addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) to represent IPv4 addresses as specially formatted IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> Like Client has IP which is of IPV4 and server has IP which is of IPV6 or vice versa. What should I do in this case?

Complain. If one sides supports only IPv4 while the other side can do only IPv6 there is no direct connection possible.